# How can I restructure this RSS feed?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I'm working with an RSS feed structured like this:

Title

string1
string2

I'd like to somehow alter the feed on the fly so that it looks like this:

Title

Title (string2)

basically, I'd like to move the title string down into the RSS item description, next to second string in the RSS item.

Right now the feed is pretty standard, title + description, which the description consisting of two strings.  I'm trying to reformat it so it displays better in Twitter.  I'd like to move the title down into the description field, replacing the first string while keeping the second one around.

Sorry this is so vague.  I thought Yahoo pipes might be able to get me there, but I'm not seeing any obvious tools that would let me rearrange the composition of these elements.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do this with a RegEx module (not a filter!). It would look like:

```
Rules
In |item.title|     replace |(.*)|     with |$1 (${item.string2})|
```